# Nutch 1.19 Webgraph command error: OutlinkDb job did not succeed, job id: job_local306968781_0001, job status: FAILED, reason: NA

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I am trying to create a webgraph in Apache Nutch after performing crawling. This is the command I am using to create the webgraph.

`bin/nutch webgraph -segmentDir crawl/segments/ -webgraphdb crawl/webgraphdb`

I get this error after running it.

```
OutlinkDb job did not succeed, job id: job_local306968781_0001, job status: FAILED, reason: NA
2023-04-23 02:32:53,083 ERROR o.a.n.s.w.WebGraph [main] WebGraph: java.lang.RuntimeException: OutlinkDb job did not succeed, job id: job_local306968781_0001, job status: FAILED, reason: NA
    at org.apache.nutch.scoring.webgraph.WebGraph.createWebGraph(WebGraph.java:610)
    at org.apache.nutch.scoring.webgraph.WebGraph.run(WebGraph.java:809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:81)
    at org.apache.nutch.scoring.webgraph.WebGraph.main(WebGraph.java:724)
```

I see that I have 2 segments in my segments folder. I noticed the error only occurs for the second segment.

Could someone please help me to get the webgraph using Nutch and tell me where I am going wrong.